# Is it possible to use an extended class( of HttpEntity/RequestEntity) for Spring Controller methods?

Tags: java, spring

Spring allows for the Controller methods arguments to be `RequestEntity / HttpEntity` objects. These can be used to get header information.

Is it possible to extend the the above classes and use those as `@Controller` method arguments?

The use case for my project is to to expose some dedicated methods for custom headers which will be passed along with HTTP Request. Though I can simply get the headers and process them, but I am interested in knowing if it is possible to extend the above classes and have some methods(to do the processing) as part of the request object itself.

Comment: Why not to do custom transformations in interceptors or aspects?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It is always possible to extend Spring API with your application specific classes. You can provide abstraction on top of Spring layer by doing that.
But in your case, you just want to have some custom headers in your payload, which is always possible with the Default Spring API also. But you need to use proper REST client with `MultiValueMap`.